# Comparing 3d graphs in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like your help with the comparison of 3d graphs in Matlab.

Consider the following code (in step 3 I'm using [this](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26001-empirical-bivariate-cdf) function)

```
clear 
rng default

%1) Construct the matrix values
K=3;
mu = zeros(1,K);
sigma = [1 0.6 0.6; 0.6 1 0.6; 0.6 0.6 1];
N = 10^4; %number draws
values = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,N);  %matrix NxK, each row is a draw from a normal with mean mu and variance-covariance matrix sigma

%2) Compute some differences using the matrix value
r01=values(:,1)-values(:,2);
r02=values(:,1)-values(:,3);
r12=values(:,2)-values(:,3);

%3) Compute the bivariate cumulative distribution function (CDF) of [r01 r02], [r01 r12],[r02 r12] 
nxbin=10^2;
nybin=10^2;
[biv_CDF_0102,x_c_0102,y_c_0102,~]=ecdfbiv([r01 r02],nxbin,nybin);
[biv_CDF_0112,x_c_0112,y_c_0112,~]=ecdfbiv([r01 r12],nxbin,nybin);
[biv_CDF_0212,x_c_0212,y_c_0212,~]=ecdfbiv([r02 r12],nxbin,nybin);
```

Now, I want to plot the three CDFs and understand whether they look similar. I expect them to be almost equal indeed. How can I do this? The problem is that it is not easy to compare 3-d pictures. At the moment I'm doing this

```
figure
subplot(3,1,1)
surfc(x_c_0102, y_c_0102,biv_CDF_0102)
subplot(3,1,2)
surfc(x_c_0112, y_c_0112, biv_CDF_0112)
subplot(3,1,3)
surfc(x_c_0212, y_c_0212,biv_CDF_0212)
```

but it doesn't help a lot. Any better suggestion?
[image]

Comment: If you showed some pictures of what you have, I think that would make it a lot easier to answer this question.  I have to do this all the time, but my techniques often end up being data specific.

Comment: How about all of the pictures with different color overlap in one graph?

Comment: @John i've added the pictures

Comment: @BanghuaZhao yes please, add an answer if you have time

Comment: I usually compare these type of data by visualizing the difference. e.g. plot `biv_CDF_0102 - biv_CDF_0112` to see where they differ. Alternatively you could compute the average of the 3 plots `(biv_CDF_0102 + biv_CDF_0112 + biv_CDF_0212)/3` and then plot the difference of each from the average.

Comment: Why not quantify the difference? You can compute the mean, standard deviation, skewness and kurtisis for all 3, see how those differ. And you can simply compute the mean square error and/or max absolute error between the various distributions. Comparing plots is sort of a last resort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imagesc`, and `contour` to visualize the differences between your distributions.  `imcontrast` with `imagesc` I find to be particularly powerful in displaying differences between functions defined on 2D rectangular domains.

I can't draw you a picture, as I do not know what `ecdfbiv` is.  That's not standard matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. All of the plots are overlapped in one graph. The 1st plot is the red color, the 2nd plot is the green color, the 3rd plot is the blue color.

```
figure
% Red color
surf(x_c_0102, y_c_0102,biv_CDF_0102,'FaceColor', [1 0 0], 'EdgeColor', [1 0 0])
hold on
% Green color
surf(x_c_0112, y_c_0112, biv_CDF_0112,'FaceColor', [0 1 0], 'EdgeColor', [0 1 0])
hold on
% Blue color
surf(x_c_0212, y_c_0212,biv_CDF_0212,'FaceColor', [0 0 1], 'EdgeColor', [0 0 1])
hold off
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: What can I conclude from the plot?

Comment: @user3285148 You want to check whether they look similar. It is your conclusion based on the plot.